# ant fileset cannot find directory which does exist

Tags: ant, hudson

I'm running an ant build from Hudson (Ubuntu). The build fails saying:

> /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Genesys Multimedia RC/workspace/current/build.xml:34: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Genesys Multimedia RC/workspace/current/Thirdparty/current does not exist.

Extract of build.xml:

```
<property name="extraDir" location="Thirdparty" />
<property name="J323ClearJarDir" location="${extraDir}/JRC/Thirdparty/J323/dist" />
<property name="JavaThirdPartyJarDir" location="${extraDir}/current" />
<property name="genesys_jars" location="lib" />

<!--Set the libs needed for compulation-->
<path id="lib">
    <fileset dir="${genesys_jars}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${JavaThirdPartyJarDir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${frameworkClearJarsDir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${J323ClearJarDir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${jrcClearJarDir}" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
```

That directory DOES exist however. 
[image]

And this same build script was working on Hudson (Windows).

Oh what could the matter be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux's filesystem is case sensitive.
The directory is **ThirdParty** whilst the property was referring to **Thirdparty**.

I shall be switching careers to become a professional human-lampshade.